# Can the front page say if Community edited something or bumped it?

Tags: feature-request, bump

The [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) periodically bumps unanswered all posts (or something like that).

The annoying this with this is that it says that the question was Modified by Community. I look for what it modified and can't find anything. Then I realized that it was probably just bumped.

Can it just say "Bumped by Community" instead of "Edited by Community"?

Comment: Should this request be granted, please also consider some special indication, if a post was bumped to a now-deleted answer or similar, as this is equally annoying for the same reason.